# How do I change the text in a text field?

Tags: java, javafx-2, textfield, scenebuilder

I am using JavaFX Scene Builder to create my UI. I want to be able to change the text in my text field located in my SimpleController Class from other classes (mostly from a finite-state machine).

```
@FXML public TextField textDescr;
```

I tried setting up a

```
public void setText(String s) {textDescr.setText(s);}
```

in SimpleController but
Eclipse tells me "Cannot make static reference to non-static method"

```
SimpleController.setText("Some stuff");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your `SimpleController`

Try this:

```
SimpleController sc = new SimpleController();
sc.setText("Some stuff");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your set text method statically. `SimpleController.setText("Some stuff");` should be `new SimpleController().setText("Some text");`